# WPF element size stretching when in a WPF Control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF Control that I want to be resizable. As such I also want the root element of this control to be a canvas so I may absolutely position elements on this control. The problem seems to be that I can not get my Image elements to resize automatically.

Can someone please post an example of a WPF User control with a Canvas containing an Image control that resizes as the control is resized?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're going through a lot of effort when the end result you want is just an Image that resizes within your control and a Canvas that can contain other elements that you want to position later.

Why not just use a Grid as the root element that contains both an Image and a Canvas?

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestProject.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="stretchyImage"
               Source="imagesource.png"
               Stretch="Fill" />
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rectToPlaceOnImage"
                       Width="50"
                       Height="50"
                       Canvas.Left="35"
                       Canvas.Top="120"
                       Fill="Red" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```